# Docker no such file package.json when running npm install

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose

I am running Docker on Windows 10 and when I run `docker-compose up -d` I get this errror but I don't know why.

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/package.json'
npm WARN www No description
npm WARN www No repository field.
npm WARN www No README data
npm WARN www No license field.
```

Here is my **docker-compose.yaml** file

```
version: '3'
services:

  # Nginx client app server
  nginx-client:
    container_name: nginx-client
    build:
        context: ./docker/nginx-client
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 28874:3000
    volumes:
        - ./client:/var/www
    networks:
      - app-network


# Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

And here is my **Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

Comment: `RUN` is executed when image is being build, but volumes are mounted when container is launched from the image. Therfor the files that you think that should be mounted, are not thre during image build phase. You should use `COPY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because first you are building an image out of your Dockerfile, which contains this commands:

```
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN npm install
```

But right now this directory is empty. It's only after the container is created, bind mounting will take place. You can read more about it in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#service-configuration-reference), it states:

> A service definition contains configuration that is applied to each
> container started for that service, much like passing command-line
> parameters to docker run. Likewise, network and volume definitions are
> analogous to `docker network create` and `docker volume create`.

If you need to have this file available at the image build time, I'd suggest using COPY command, like:

```
COPY ./client/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
```

Comment: Oh, now that makes sense. I didn't understand this part about Docker. So the binding of volumes hasn't yet taken place at this stage. Thank you!